# 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python

```
def participant_specific(request, participant):
    helper = RelayFunctions()
    info = helper.participant_specific_donation(participant)
    info1 = helper.participant_specific_milestone(participant)

    data = { 'participant_specific_donation' : info , 'participant_specific_milestone' : info1 }
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    response = json_serializer.serialize(data, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json") 

Traceback:
 File "/home/vtrelayc/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
   111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/home/vtrelayc/projects/relay/relayapp/views.py" in participant_specific
   192.     response = json_serializer.serialize(data, ensure_ascii=False)
 File "/home/vtrelayc/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py" in serialize
   46.             concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model

 Exception Type: AttributeError at /participants/specific/1/
 Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Error: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

We're trying to parse the dictionary but it says it's a string?  Is it because of the multiple objects in one dictionary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

json_serializer.serialize is supposed to be used with a queryset.  More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/serialization/#id2).

You should be able to achieve the same with this:

```
import json
data = json.dumps({ 'participant_specific_donation' : info , 'participant_specific_milestone' : info1 })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link is 404'ing...rather post a bit of code along with the link

Answer (score 7):

Django's serializers are only for serializing `QuerySet`s, but you're passing it a `dict`. If you want to serialize a `dict`, perhaps you're looking for [Python's built-in `json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: This is a great, straightforward answer. Thank you @icktoofay.