# Accessing dict values in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm having trouble accessing the values of a dict object that I'm trying to send to a template in Django. I can access and print the dict's contents in my view, but when I try to send the data to my template there are all kinds of characters like it isn't encoded properly. At first I thought it might have been an issue with serializing, but I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794677/str-object-has-no-attribute-meta) which states that json_serializer.serialize is supposed to be used with a queryset. Is this correct? From here I tried the following.

At first I tried to just send the data variable by itself without any formatting like so

```
data = {'item_1': 123, 'item_2': 456, 'item_3': ['a','b','c'] }
return render(request, 'testsite/new_page.html', {'data' : data} )
```

In the template I have the following

```
<script>var data = "{{ data }}"; </script>
<script>console.log(data);</script>

// displays the following
// &lt;testsite.views.data object at 0x1045f1e48&gt;
```

Then I tried to format the data to JSON

```
data = {'item_1': 123, 'item_2': 456, 'item_3': ['a','b','c'] }
return render(request, 'testsite/new_page.html', {'data' : json.dumps(data.__dict__) } )

//template
<script>var data = "{{ data }}"; </script>
<script>console.log(data);</script>

// the following is the improperly formatted result
// {&quot;item_1&quot;: 123, &quot;item_2&quot;: 456, &quot;item_3&quot;: [&quot;a&quot;,&quot;b&quot;,&quot;c&quot;,]
```

If I don't use `json.dumps(data.__dict__)` and instead just have `json.dumps(data)` I get an error about the object is not JSON serializable

In my view I have the following. The contents of the dict are properly formatted.

```
print(data.__dict__)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

# displays the dict properly
# {'item_1': 123, 'item_2': 456, 'item_3': ['a','b','c'] }
```

In the template tried to iterate through the data object using javascript like so, but it just displays each individual character of the improperly formatted dict.

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(data[key]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing the improperly formatted data in the template?

Comment: Can't you just do `return render(request, 'testsite/new_page.html', {'data' : data} )`?

Comment: Sorry, I should update. When I do that it results in a strange result with what appears to be a memory location. I'll update my post

Comment: <script>var data = "{{ data }}"; </script>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

consider using

```
return render(request, 'testsite/new_page.html', {'serialized_data' :json.dumps(data) } )
```

with

```
<script>var data = "{{ serialized_data | safe }}"; </script>
```

Note the `safe` filter there stops django to turn your `"` into `&quot;`

Comment: When I do this I get a reference error ReferenceError: data is not defined. I made sure to account for your answer how you used serialized_data rather than data like I have. Still results in reference answer, same as with what e4c5's answer

Comment: @user1852176 plz adjust the variable names according to your code

Comment: I did that but forgot to mention that in my comment. I must have changed my comment before you saw it. The other answer also results in a reference error.

Comment: For those of you reading this in the future, I was able to get it to work by switching to single quotes and using `json.dumps(data.__dict__)` in my view and using single quotes rather than double when setting the javascript variable `<script>var data = '{{ serialized_data | safe }}'; </script>`